# Add an object to multiple others and put the results into an array

Tags: json, jq

I have many objects like

```
   {
      "name":"blablabla1",
      "something": "blablabla"
      "something2": "blablabla"
   }
   {
      "name":"blablabla2",
      "something": "blablabla"
      "something2": "blablabla"
   }
   {
      "name":"blablabla3",
      "something": "blablabla"
      "something2": "blablabla"
   }
```

I need to merge them with jq, like

```
jq -s '.' firstone.json secondone.json thirdone.json
```

After merge, I get:

```
[
   {
      "name":"blablabla1",
      "something": "blablabla"
      "something2": "blablabla"
   },   
   {
      "name":"blablabla2",
      "something": "blablabla"
      "something2": "blablabla"
   },   
   {
      "name":"blablabla3",
      "something": "blablabla"
      "something2": "blablabla"
   }
]
```

but I want to add in every object - another one:

```
   {
      "thisMustBeInEveryarray": "thisone"
   }
```

But like:

```
[
   {
      "name":"blablabla1",
      "something": "blablabla"
      "something2": "blablabla"
      "thisMustBeInEveryarray": "thisone"
   },   
   {
      "name":"blablabla2",
      "something": "blablabla"
      "something2": "blablabla"
      "thisMustBeInEveryarray": "thisone"
   },   
   {
      "name":"blablabla3",
      "something": "blablabla"
      "something2": "blablabla"
      "thisMustBeInEveryarray": "thisone"
   }
]
```

Is it even possible to be done in one iteration with jq? Because if I merge them like 
`jq -s '.' firstone.json secondone.json thirdone.json mustbeinevery.json`, I get `mustbeinevery.json` just like the last element of the whole array.

Answer (score 1):

Specify `mustbeinevery.json` as the first input so that you can refer to others by `inputs` keyword, and add them inside an array constructor.

```
jq '[inputs+.]' mustbeinevery.json firstone.json secondone.json thirdone.json
```